# QComboBox with click to lineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I wish derived class from QComboBox with following additional feature:

When user clicks to QLiineEdit of this combo box, the effect have to be the same as click to arrow on the right side of combo box (showPopup() method).

My attemption is:

File lineedit.h

```
#ifndef LINEEDIT_H
#define LINEEDIT_H

#include <QLineEdit>

class LineEdit : public QLineEdit {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  LineEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:
  void pressed();

protected:
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // LINEEDIT_H
```

File lineedit.cpp

```
#include "lineedit.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>

LineEdit::LineEdit(QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(parent) {}

void LineEdit::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
  QLineEdit::mousePressEvent(event);
  emit pressed();
  event->accept();
}
```

File combobox.h

```
#ifndef COMBOBOX_H
#define COMBOBOX_H

#include <QComboBox>

class ComboBox : public QComboBox {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  ComboBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private slots:
  void lineEditPressed();
};

#endif // COMBOBOX_H
```

File combobox.cpp

```
#include "combobox.h"
#include "lineedit.h"

ComboBox::ComboBox(QWidget *parent) : QComboBox(parent) {
  setLineEdit(new LineEdit);
  connect(lineEdit(), SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(lineEditPressed()));
}

void ComboBox::lineEditPressed() { showPopup(); }
```

But, when I press lineEdit, it shows popup, but after releasing mouse button it vanishes.

Comment: [`QComboBox` hides the pop-up on mouse release](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox.cpp.html#749) in some cases. This could be interfering with your implementation.

Comment: I solved problem by following steps: 1. adding boolean attribute preventHidePopup in ComboBox class, 2. reimplementing hidePopup() method in ComboBox class to check this attribute and call QComboBox::showPopup() if this attribute value is false and finally set this attribute to false. 3. Initializing this attribute to flase in constructor. 4. setting this attribute to true before showPopup() method call  in ComboBox::lineEditPressed() slot.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, revise the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) of the event handler. As you show pop-up menu in this function, then the release event will conflict hastily. I can't predict your implementation of `showPopup()`, but please don't create a pop-up menu inside it. You may show, hide, assign, but **NEVER** create.

Comment: Thanx for your answer but it does not help me. I did not reimplemented showPopup, but used inherited method from QComboBox. Please, tell me how to solve it. Write the simple derived class with such feature.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that `showPopup()` is a reimplemented function. I mean that this is your implementation, but take care of what you're doing inside it. If you still can't understand, then I recommend editing the post to add the implementation of this function.

Comment: There is no my implementation of showPopup() method. The QComboBox class has showPopup() method.

Comment: Seems like it's a Qt problem, and you need to override `showPopup()`. I'm sorry, but I hope I could help.